# Recursively go through array of objects to create parent child relationships

Tags: javascript

i have an array of objects looks like this:

```
arr =[{
    refno: "1",
    name : "section-1"
 },{
    refno: "1.1",
    name : "section-1.1"
 },{
    refno: "1.1.1",
    name : "section-1.1.1"
 },{
    refno: "1.1.2",
    name : "section-1.1.2"
 },{
    refno: "1.1.3",
    name : "section-1.1.3"
 },{
    refno: "1.2",
    name : "section-1.2"
 },{
    refno: "1.2.1",
    name : "section-1.2.1"
 }]
```

i need to convert this array like this:

```
[{
    "1": {
        name: "Section-1",
        children: [{
            "1.1": {
                name: "Section-1.1",
                children: [{
                    "1.1.1": {
                        name: "Section-1.1.1",
                        children: []
                    },
                    "1.1.2": {
                        name: "Section-1.1.2",
                        children: []
                    },
                     "1.1.2": {
                        name: "Section-1.1.3",
                        children: []
                    }
                }]
            },
            "1.2": {
                name: "Section-1.2",
                children: [{
                    name: "Section-1.2",
                    children: {
                        "1.2.1": {
                            name: "Section-1.2.1",
                            children: []
                        }
                    }
                }]
            }]
        }
    }
}]
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please look at your question and notice that you did not format it properly. Hit edit, and then update it, using the syntax that Stackoverflow requires. Having said that, also please remember that SO is _not_ a general help forum. Please explain what you have already tried, show the code you wrote, explain what it did and how that wasn't what you expected, and what you searched for to help you figure things out but didn't end up helping. Stackoverflow is your "last resort" after first trying to do things yourself, and then getting properly stuck.

Comment: why are children arrays, if always is a single object in it?

Answer (score 1):

I have worked hard for it. The output might differ for yours very slightly. Please check the code and output. [Gist](https://gist.github.com/vishubhardwaj911/48db4d548fcdbe09243e95fdad53fe5f)

```js
var arr =[{
    refno: "1",
    name : "section-1"
 },{
    refno: "1.1",
    name : "section-1.1"
 },{
    refno: "1.1.1",
    name : "section-1.1.1"
 },{
    refno: "1.1.2",
    name : "section-1.1.2"
 },{
    refno: "1.1.3",
    name : "section-1.1.3"
 },{
    refno: "1.2",
    name : "section-1.2"
 },{
    refno: "1.2.1",
    name : "section-1.2.1"
 }];
 
function hasKey2(arr, key) {
  let index = -1;
  for (let x of arr) {
    if (x[key] != undefined) {
      index = x;
      break;
    }
  }
  return index;
}

function main(arr) {
  let output = [];
  for (let element of arr) {
    const refno = element.refno;
    const refArr = element.refno.split(".");
    let tempArr = output;
    let markSection = "section-";
    for (let ref of refArr) {
      markSection = markSection + ref;
      let ind = hasKey2(tempArr, ref);
      if (ind != -1) {
        tempArr = ind[ref].children;
      } else {
        tempArr.push({
          [ref]: {
            name: markSection,
            children: []
          }
        });
        tempArr = tempArr[tempArr.length - 1][ref].children;
      }
      markSection = markSection + ".";
    }
  }
  console.log("Output ", output);
  return output;
}

main(arr);
```

And the output is the following.

```
[{"1":{"name":"section-1","children":[{"1":{"name":"section-1.1","children":[{"1":{"name":"section-1.1.1","children":[]}},{"2":{"name":"section-1.1.2","children":[]}},{"3":{"name":"section-1.1.3","children":[]}}]}},{"2":{"name":"section-1.2","children":[{"1":{"name":"section-1.2.1","children":[]}}]}}]}}]
```